# Which plot to use for data spanned on multiple years?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've a dataset of - Number of accidents that happens in each state. The dataset spans from 2001 to 2014.

Which plot should I use to represent the information - number of accidents in each state per year,  in 1 plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time data, you should often use a simple **Line Chart**, with time on the X axis and the other variable dependent of time (here the number of accident) on the Y axis. Since you have several states to plot, you can simply draw one line for each state. to differentiate them, you can use a **visualization variable** : color, width, pattern ... Color is probably the most relevant here. You can as well write the name of the state near each line.

Comment: Yea Got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use matplotlib (Multiple plots with scrollable window).
Consider X axis as year and Y axis as state name.

The links below might help you.

[Scrollbar on matplotlib showing page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42622146/9214357)

[Topographic hillshading](https://matplotlib.org/examples/specialty_plots/topographic_hillshading.html)